# Get an accurate percentage calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to divide one number by another in a SQL view.  I'm dividing two columns that are each of type `int`, and the problem is that its giving me a rounded output, rather than an accurate one.

Here is my select:

```
SELECT numberOne, numberTwo, (numberOne*100/NULLIF(numberTwo, 0)) as PctOutput
```

This is working, but when it dives 3 by 37 its giving me 8 instead of 8.108.

How would I modify this to give me an accurate answer?  Do I need to cast the  numbers out of ints?  if so - into what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    **--Cast the denominator as Float**
    SELECT 3 * 100 / NULLIF(CAST(37 AS FLOAT),0) -- 8.10810810810811

    **--Multiply by 1.0 in either numerator OR denominator**
    SELECT 3 * 100 / NULLIF(37 * 1.0,0) -- 8.108108
    SELECT 3.0 * 100 / NULLIF(37,0) -- 8.108108


    **--Convert it to decimal** 
    SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,13), 3) * 100 / 
           NULLIF(CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,13), 37),0) -- 8.108108108
```

Comment: You don't have to convert both numerator and denominator. If you simply need to avoid integer division, it is enough to convert just one of the two.

Answer (score 3):

Try an implicit cast:

```
SELECT 
   numberOne, 
   numberTwo, 
   ((1.0*numberOne)*100/NULLIF(1.0*numberTwo, 0)) as PctOutput
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to write `SELECT numberOne, numberTwo, NULLIF(100.0*numberOne/(1.0*numberTwo),0) as PctOutput` to avoid a divison by zero?

Comment: @dgw: Actually danihp's solution does account for zero division, while yours would result in the error.

Comment: @AndriyM You are right. I mixed up `NULLIF` and `IFNULL`. My fault.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server the result is always of the same type as the inputs. So yes you do need to convert the inputs.

I generally convert using `convert(decimal(9,2),numberOne)` but depending you may want to `convert(real,numberOne)` or use a different level of precision.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the numbers from INT into either float or decimal.

If you use literals, they will likely be decimal (NUMERIC), not float (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072806/sql-server-calculation-with-numeric-literals)

Note that if you use decimal, you should be aware of the rules of scale and precision in division if you have numbers near the boundaries where you might lose precision:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx